# Please explain the format and use of "dir nach Hause"

Tags: preposition

1. I am a little confused about the fine points of this expression.  I believe I understand that if I wrote "Ich komme nach Hause" it would be understood that it means I am coming to my house (where I live), and therefore one would never write "Ich komme zu mir nach Hause."  Am I correct?
2. I also assume if I am coming to her house, it would be "Ich komme zu ihr nach Hause." Is that correct?
3. What about  coming to our house?  Would it be then "Wir kommen nach Hause" or would it be Wir kommen zu uns nach Hause?"
   Thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. It makes sense to specify this. Imagine you're talking to your partner but you live in separate houses. Simply saying "Ich komme nach Hause" could imply either home, so to clarify or avoid confusion it is correct to say

   > Ich komme zu mir nach Hause

   Although probably  *gehen* instead of *kommen* would be a bit more idiomatic.
2. That's correct.
3. Both options are correct, and again, it depends only on if you want to be overly specific (which can make sense, see 1.)

Overall, the general expression is

> zu jemandem nach Hause kommen

Where *jemand* can either be a name, a personal pronoun (dative case), or another specifier (again in dative).

> Ich komme zu Sarah nach Hause
> Ich komme zu meiner Schwester nach Hause
> Ich komme zu ihr nach Hause

Comment: That is all extremely helpful.  The general expression is especially enlightening, as it explains exactly why the construction is what it is.  To be honest, that's what I really wanted to ask, but I couldn't decide how to ask it in a way that made sense, so I used the examples instead.  I am glad that I did use the examples, though, because your answers on the examples were also very helpful in gaining full understanding.  Thank you for taking the time for such a helpful and complete answer.

Comment: @BambergWein If you think the answer is good, please upvote it. If the answer resolves your question, please "accept" it (by selecting the check-sign next to it).